# Add new id to each div that contains the same class

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm looking to see how I can take a certain div that will have the same class and add and ID to it but increase for each new ID count a number up for example the default html would be like this.

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

What I would like to than be able to do is auto add an ID called id="section-1" and for each div add 1 so the second div would be id="section-2"

So the output would look like

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="section-1" class="section"></div>
    <div id="section-2" class="section"></div>
    <div id="section-3" class="section"></div>
    <div id="section-4" class="section"></div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if I can do this with PHP I was thinking I could do something like

```
$Variable = the way to add +1 for each div than 
<div id="section-<?php echo $Variable ?>" class="section"></div>
```

I may be way off on how I'm going about this so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to determine how many section div you want?

Comment: The amount of section divs will vary depending on each post which is why I need to figure out a way to run through and see how many divs i have with the section class than add the proper section id to it

Comment: you can do this by using loop!

Comment: Ok. So rather than adding +1 to the div can't you add a unique number to that post. Something like id of that post?

Answer (score 1):

not sure,but like this we can assign the id's

```
for($i=1;$i<=$your_posts_value;$i++)
{
?>
<div id="section-<?=$i ?>" class="section">test</div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: I'm going to be using this with wordpress would this work with having to use wordpress <?php the_content(); ?>

Comment: What do i set $your_posts_value to?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use for loop.

```
for($i=1; $i <= $count_of_section_div; $i++)
{
    echo '<div id="section-'.$i.'" class="section"></div>';
}
```

Comment: Why I try testing this none of the divs even show up.

Comment: what is $count_of_section_div value you get?

Comment: What do you mean? nothing shows at all when I copy the code that you did onto the site, no divs display at all. Am i suppose to set $count_of_section_div = to something?

Comment: Oh boy! You need to assign `$count_of_section_div` to the number of section div's you want display. For example add `$count_of_section_div = 4;` line first and then add above code.

Comment: But I don't know how many sections I will have since each post will have a different section of divs, which is what I"m trying to do do is have the code figure out the section of divs I have.

Comment: So how will you get the content of the div? you must be running some query right? So you can get number of div's from that.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<div id="content">
    <?php 
    while($Variable <= 4)
    {
    ?>
           <div id="section-<?php echo $Variable ?>" class="section"></div>
    <?php
           $Variable++;
    } 
    ?>

</div>
```

Comment: that works but I'm not going to know exactly how many divs I will need so I need it to go through the code and see how many divs there are than add to them, some times there may be 4, other posts there may be 8